# Ways to reverse a cavity before it goes rotten?

Tags: dentistry, cavity

I was at the dentist for a checkup today and I was asking about a small black bit in my back tooth. He said it will eventually become a cavity and need a filling but for now it's fine and depending on how I look after my teeth it could be ok for a while.

I found this a very odd thing to hear. It makes very little sense to me that there is nothing that can be done now to mitigate the effects in the future. I don't want to pay another €50 for a second opinion, so I'm wondering if he was right. Is there nothing that can be done during the early stages of a cavity to prevent it needing a full on filling in the future?

Answer (score 4):

Mainly with fluoridated toothpaste **and** sugar restriction. See

1. http://www.ada.org/en/member-center/oral-health-topics/dental-sealants
2. http://www.ada.org/en/public-programs/advocating-for-the-public/fluoride-and-fluoridation/fluoride-clinical-guidelines
3. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20831358
4. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10343087